# mediaQueries properties in css is not working in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, media-queries

I am learning reactjs and encountered a problem while displaying the properties in media queries. What I am trying to do is to display the `hamburger` I built using CSS.

- For width > 799px : It should NOT be displayed i.e. `display:none`
- For width <= 799px : It should be displayed i.e. `display:block`

Attached CSS files

When width>799px;

```
/* hamburger menu */
.header .headerContainer_hamburgerMenu {
 display: none;
 background-color: var(--font-color);
 height: 2px;
 width: 1.2rem;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-right: 1rem;
 } 

.header .headerContainer_hamburgerMenu::before, .header .headerContainer_hamburgerMenu::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: var(--font-color);
  height: 2px;
  width: 1.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
 }
 .header .headerContainer_hamburgerMenu::before {
    transform: translateY(-7px);
  }
 .header .headerContainer_hamburgerMenu::after {
    transform: translateY(5px);
  }
```

- when width<799px:

  ```
   @media only screen and (max-width:799px) {

   .header .headerContainer_hamburgerMenu {
       display: block;
      }  
   }
  ```

On inspecting element, I got this

[image: insoect element]

I am also attaching the picture of the hamburger

[image]

I also intentionally displayed the hamburger for the desktop view to show you where I want this in the navbar in the given pic

[image]

Comment: Could you provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? media queries should work, the react does not affect it

Comment: Please check the complete code here https://github.com/mohitm15/DevCommunity-clone